# confirmbox() with different appearance

Tags: javascript

I need a confirm box with different a appearance?

the default look for confirm() is this.. I don't want this confirmbox design.

[image]

confirm("Get a message?");

Comment: Look up modal windows or just work around using confirm boxes - they can be annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) or any other dialog plugins.

Answer (score 1):

That dialog can not be styled. Your only option is to use custom javascript widget library.

To find a complete library of various widgets you can [google for "javascript widgets"](http://www.google.lt/search?q=javascript%20widgets) or simply use [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/) (specifically [jQuery UI dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)).

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of the 'confirm' and 'alert' methods in JS are governed solely by the browser and cannot be changed in code.

I suggest using jQuery and a suitable plug-in like this one: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/. You'll be able to change the appearance and it'll be the same over all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the appearance of a confirm so you are stuck the look that the browser gives you. You can create your own confirm type of control yourself with HTML/JavaScript/CSS, but the issue is it will not pause execution and wait for a user's response. So coding confirms for form submissions gets a little tricky.